# Why won't my header display my GraphQL provided share image thumbnail properly?

Tags: html, facebook, graphql

I've included a title tag, an image tag, an image width tag, an image height tag, and an image secure url tag. The docs specify only needing a title tag and image tag. I've tried that. And slowly added these others. I've moved stuff around. I've added. Removed. Made a new image. But nothing makes the image show properly in a share link. I'm banging my head against the wall.

Absolutely perplexing is that if you run Facebook's debugging tool on audreysmonsters.com it says at the top that the image url had to be inferred and that it's missing an image tag. But it's there. And you can actually see the tag if you scroll down to rules_url_dev. Wtf.

Debugger:

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/?q=audreysmonsters.com

Doc:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/webmasters/getting-started/basic-link

```
 <head>
    <meta property=”og:title” content=”Tristans Portfolio Website” />
    <meta property=”og:type” content=”website” />
    <meta property=”og:url” content=”https://audreysmonsters.com/” />
    <meta property=”og:description” content=”An iOS Developer portfolio website displaying the work of Tristan Jackson” />
    <meta property=”og:image” content=”https://audreysmonsters.com/img/WebsiteImage.png” />
    <meta property="og:image:width" content="1200" />
    <meta property="og:image:height" content="627" />
    <metA property="og:image:secure_url" content=”https://audreysmonsters.com/img/WebsiteImage.png” />
    ...

</head>
```

Answer (score 0):

Omg I figured it out. The ""s. I had the wrong kind of quotes... inconsistently.